# Deleting like from a post on facebook with graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm trying to remove a like from a post on facebook using graph api. Like facebook's docs said i do this by requesting POST_ID/likes through HTTP DELETE verb. But neither a post on my wall nor another pages' wall couldn't be deleted with this request.

When i try it with graph api explorer i see an error like despite i have the permission through an access token;

```
{
  error: {
    type: "OAuthException",
    message: "(#200) Permissions error",
  }
}
```

Could be there an error on facebook graph api with the DELETE operation?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need a permission to do this which is the `publish_stream` permission.

More about this can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).